# Find the matrix of the given linear transformation T with respect to the given basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGrcE.png)

I'm not sure where to start with number 6. Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that a matrix is usually "at the same level as linear maps", but in the exercise, the *vectors* are matrices. So we have matrices ät two different levels. By following the definition of "matrix associated with a linear transformation" word by word, we shouldn't have any problem.

$U^{2\times 2}$ is, I guess, the vector space of upper-triangular matrices, and we are given a basis $\mathfrak{B}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$. Call $V_1,V_2,V_3$ the elements of the basis in the order they are written.

The transformation we consider is
$$T(M)=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}M$$
By definition, the matrix of $T$ is the $3\times 3$ matrix $A_T=[a_{ij}]$ such that for each $j$, $T(V_j)=\sum_{i=1}^3 a_{ij}V_i$.

We have
$$T(V_1)=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=V_1+0V_2+0V_3$$
This gives the first column of $A_T$:
$$A_T=\begin{bmatrix}1&*&*\\0&*&*\\0&*&*\end{bmatrix}$$

I'll let you calculate the other columns on your own. (It will probably be a little harder than the case above: you have to find $a_{12},a_{22},a_{32}$ such that $T(V_2)=a_{12}V_1+a_{22}V_2+a_{32}V_3$, so you should solve a linear system on $3$ variables $a_{i2}$, and similarly for $T(V_3)$.)